# UIWebView started twice - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiprogressview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am using the below to add a `ProgressView` while the `UIWebView` is loading and dismissing it when it's done.
The problem is the UIWebView is started twice and also the ProgressView, So when the page is done loading only one ProgressView is dismissed and the other one doesn't.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DirectionViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *directionWebView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController () 
    @property UIColor *yellowColor;
    @property MRProgressOverlayView *progressView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.yellowColor =
    [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f
                    green:208.0f/255.0f
                     blue:63.0f/255.0f
                    alpha:1.0f];
    self.directionWebView.delegate = self;
    NSString *urlMap = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f,%f&zoom=14", @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=", self.coordLat, self.coordLong];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlMap];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.directionWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"WebView start loading...");
    self.progressView = [MRProgressOverlayView new];
    self.progressView.mode = MRProgressOverlayViewModeIndeterminateSmall;
    [self.view.window addSubview:self.progressView];
    [self.progressView setTintColor:self.yellowColor];
    [self.progressView setTitleLabelText:@"Loading ..."];
    [self.progressView show:YES];
    return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     [self.progressView dismiss:YES];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know why it is calling twice but you can do this.

```
if(!self.progressView){
self.progressView = [MRProgressOverlayView new];
    self.progressView.mode = MRProgressOverlayViewModeIndeterminateSmall;
    [self.view.window addSubview:self.progressView];
    [self.progressView setTintColor:self.yellowColor];
    [self.progressView setTitleLabelText:@"Loading ..."];
    [self.progressView show:YES];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     [self.progressView dismiss:YES];
self.progressView  = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KDeogharkar

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This delegate method can be called multiple times (in case of redirection for example). So I would recommend to move your Progress view init code to **viewDidLoad** method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...
    self.progressView = [MRProgressOverlayView new];
    self.progressView.mode = MRProgressOverlayViewModeIndeterminateSmall;
    [self.view.window addSubview:self.progressView];
    [self.progressView setTintColor:self.yellowColor];
    [self.progressView setTitleLabelText:@"Loading ..."];
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"WebView start loading...");
    [self.progressView show:YES];
    return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.progressView dismiss:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

it may be triggered more than once, e.g redirects, `iframe` loading and so on. It's very inconvenient to initialise objects here.

Use `Lazy Initialization` design pattern for it

```
- (MRProgressOverlayView *)progressView {
    if (_progressView) {
        _progressView = [... alloc] init];
        // ... setup your progressView
    }
    return _progressView;
}
```

btw, you forgot about error handling:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // You need to stop loading indicator here, right?!
}
```

Second thing is - (maybe for you case it's not a big deal) but usually it's tricky to exactly determine when UIWebView stopped loading (all the resources loaded, AJAX requests and so on)

Personally I'm using something like code below to manage activity indicator start/stop behaviour for `UIWebView`

```
#pragma mark UIWebViewDelegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Webview (%p) starting to load URL: %@", self, request.URL);
    self.URL = request.URL;
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
    self.webViewLoadingCount++;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    self.webViewLoadingCount--;
    if (self.webViewLoadingCount > 0) return;
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    self.webViewLoadingCount--;

    [self.spinner stopAnimating];

    // Ignore NSURLErrorDomain error (-999).
    if (error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) return;

    // Ignore "Frame Load Interrupted" errors 
    if (error.code == 102 && [error.domain isEqual:@"WebKitErrorDomain"]) return;

    NSLog(@"WebView (%p) experienced an error: %@.", self, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```